# Java date parsing not working for ET timezone while working for IST

Tags: java, date, timezone, date-parsing

I am trying to parse the String to date. String having date format as 
"dd-MMM-yyyy Z" and String having value "12-DEC-2018 ET". Its giving the error 
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "12-DEC-2018 ET".

The same code is working for String having value "12-DEC-2018 IST". 
below is the code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String dateInputIST ="12-DEC-2018 IST";
    String dateInputET ="12-DEC-2018 ET";

    SimpleDateFormat sdfmt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy Z");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfmt2= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Date dDate = sdfmt1.parse( dateInputIST );
    String strOutput = sdfmt2.format( dDate );

    System.out.println(strOutput);

    Date etDate = sdfmt1.parse(dateInputET);
    strOutput = sdfmt2.format(etDate);

    System.out.println(strOutput);

}
```

Could someone please help. I needed to parse the time in any timezone.
Thanks,
Navin

Comment: Do you mean `EDT` instead of `ET`?

Comment: Parsing of time zone abbreviations is fragile in any case. I at least would not know whether `IST` would be parsed into the time of Iceland, Ireland, Israel or India. So avoid relying on them if there’s any way you can. Also when Eastern Time is a correct designation of the time zone using EST during standard time and EDT dirung summer.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: On my computer you program parses your IST string into Tue Dec 11 23:00:00 CET 2018, which is formatted into `11/12/2018`. Is it intended behaviour that the date is one day earlier?

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
 String dateInputET ="12-DEC-2018 ET";
```

to

```
 String dateInputET ="12-DEC-2018 EDT";
```

'ET' is not a recognized time zone.

Answer (score 3):

## Pseudo-zones

ET, EST, and IST are not actually time zones. Those 2-4 letter pseudo-zones are not standardized and are not even unique! For example, IST can mean India Standard Time, Ireland Standard Time, Iceland Standard Time, and more.

Real time zone names take the format  of `Continent/Region` such as `Africa/Tunis`.

## Date & zone, separately

Date with time zone has no real meaning.

Handle the date as a `LocalDate` object.

```
String input = "12-DEC-2018"
DayeTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" , Locale.US ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Handle your desired time zone separately, as a `ZoneId` object.

```
ZoneId zNewYork = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
```

To combine, determine the first moment of the day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtNewYork = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Generate text representing that moment in standard ISO 8601 format extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.

To see that same moment in UTC, extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdtNewYork.toInstant() ;
```

Adjust into another zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) ;
```

To focus on the date only, get a `LocalDate` for  the day of that same moment when viewed through the lens of the wall-clock time used in India.

```
LocalDate ldKolkata = zdtKolkata.toLocalDate() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateZoneFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu v")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

    String dateInputIST ="12-DEC-2018 IST";
    String dateInputET ="12-DEC-2018 ET";

    TemporalAccessor parsed = dateZoneFormatter.parse(dateInputIST);
    System.out.println("Date: " + LocalDate.from(parsed) + " Time zone: " + ZoneId.from(parsed));

    parsed = dateZoneFormatter.parse(dateInputET);
    System.out.println("Date: " + LocalDate.from(parsed) + " Time zone: " + ZoneId.from(parsed));
```

On my computer the output from this snippet was:

> ```
> Date: 2018-12-12 Time zone: Atlantic/Reykjavik
> Date: 2018-12-12 Time zone: America/New_York
> ```

Format pattern letter `v` is for the *generic time-zone name*, that is, the name that is the same all year regardless of summer time (DST), for example Eastern Time or short ET.

If you want to control the interpretation of ambiguous time zone abbreviations (of which there are a lot), you may use the two-arg `appendGenericZoneText​(TextStyle, Set<ZoneId>)` where the second argument contains the preferred zones. Still better if there is a way for you to avoid relying on time zone abbreviations altogether since, as I said, they are very often ambiguous.

I am not sure what sense a date with a time zone makes, though.

As an additional point, always specify locale for your formatters so they will also work if the default locale is changed or one day your program runs in a JVM with a different default locale.

### Avoid SimpleDateFormat and Date

I don’t think `SimpleDateFormat` will be able to parse your string. It’s just the same since that class is already long outdated and is renowned for being troublesome, so you should never want to use it anyway.